# bundle install errors on carrierwave gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, carrierwave

I am trying to install a gem(carrierwave) and when I use the command bundle install I am having an error like this:

> Invalid gemspec in
>   [/home/sup1re/superrrr/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/specifications/carrierwave-0.6.2.gemspec]:
>   Illformed requirement ["#
>   1.1.4"]

And

> Installing carrierwave (0.6.2) Invalid gemspec in
>   [/home/sup1re/superrrr/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/specifications/carrierwave-0.6.2.gemspec]:
>   Illformed requirement ["#
>   1.1.4"]

I also trien to run the "`gem update --system`"

and I got this error

[image]

[[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RUxW9.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RUxW9.png)

Specs:

> ruby 1.8.7 (2011-02-18 patchlevel 334) [x86_64-linux]
>
> Rails 3.2.3
>
> Gem version is 1.8.5

I wonder what is the problem with my Gemfile.

Any comments are very welcome.
Thank you.

**Here is the carrierwave-0.6.2.gemspec that causes the error**

```
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-

Gem::Specification.new do |s|
  s.name = %q{carrierwave}
  s.version = "0.6.2"

  s.required_rubygems_version = Gem::Requirement.new(">= 0") if s.respond_to? :required_rubygems_version=
  s.authors = [%q{Jonas Nicklas}]
  s.date = %q{2012-04-12}
  s.description = %q{Upload files in your Ruby applications, map them to a range of ORMs, store them on different backends.}
  s.email = [%q{jonas.nicklas@gmail.com}]
  s.extra_rdoc_files = [%q{README.md}]
  s.files = [%q{README.md}]
  s.homepage = %q{https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave}
  s.rdoc_options = [%q{--main}]
  s.require_paths = [%q{lib}]
  s.rubyforge_project = %q{carrierwave}
  s.rubygems_version = %q{1.8.5}
  s.summary = %q{Ruby file upload library}

  if s.respond_to? :specification_version then
    s.specification_version = 3

    if Gem::Version.new(Gem::VERSION) >= Gem::Version.new('1.2.0') then
      s.add_runtime_dependency(%q<activesupport>, [">= 3.2.0"])
      s.add_runtime_dependency(%q<activemodel>, [">= 3.2.0"])
      s.add_development_dependency(%q<mysql2>, [">= 0"])
      s.add_development_dependency(%q<rails>, [">= 3.2.0"])
      s.add_development_dependency(%q<cucumber>, ["#<YAML::Syck::DefaultKey:0x718a860d0a98> 1.1.4"])
      s.add_development_dependency(%q<json>, [">= 0"])
      s.add_development_dependency(%q<rspec>, ["~> 2.0"])
      s.add_development_dependency(%q<sham_rack>, [">= 0"])
      s.add_development_dependency(%q<timecop>, [">= 0"])
      s.add_development_dependency(%q<fog>, [">= 1.3.1"])
      s.add_development_dependency(%q<mini_magick>, [">= 0"])
      s.add_development_dependency(%q<rmagick>, [">= 0"])
    else
      s.add_dependency(%q<activesupport>, [">= 3.2.0"])
      s.add_dependency(%q<activemodel>, [">= 3.2.0"])
      s.add_dependency(%q<mysql2>, [">= 0"])
      s.add_dependency(%q<rails>, [">= 3.2.0"])
      s.add_dependency(%q<cucumber>, ["#<YAML::Syck::DefaultKey:0x718a860d0a98> 1.1.4"])
      s.add_dependency(%q<json>, [">= 0"])
      s.add_dependency(%q<rspec>, ["~> 2.0"])
      s.add_dependency(%q<sham_rack>, [">= 0"])
      s.add_dependency(%q<timecop>, [">= 0"])
      s.add_dependency(%q<fog>, [">= 1.3.1"])
      s.add_dependency(%q<mini_magick>, [">= 0"])
      s.add_dependency(%q<rmagick>, [">= 0"])
    end
  else
    s.add_dependency(%q<activesupport>, [">= 3.2.0"])
    s.add_dependency(%q<activemodel>, [">= 3.2.0"])
    s.add_dependency(%q<mysql2>, [">= 0"])
    s.add_dependency(%q<rails>, [">= 3.2.0"])
    s.add_dependency(%q<cucumber>, ["#<YAML::Syck::DefaultKey:0x718a860d0a98> 1.1.4"])
    s.add_dependency(%q<json>, [">= 0"])
    s.add_dependency(%q<rspec>, ["~> 2.0"])
    s.add_dependency(%q<sham_rack>, [">= 0"])
    s.add_dependency(%q<timecop>, [">= 0"])
    s.add_dependency(%q<fog>, [">= 1.3.1"])
    s.add_dependency(%q<mini_magick>, [">= 0"])
    s.add_dependency(%q<rmagick>, [">= 0"])
  end
end
```

Comment: please paste you error log in proper format not an image.

Comment: I pasted the error and I also include the image so that others will have a visual representation of my error. Thanks for your advice

Comment: Are you have installed your rubygems from repo? Which OS do you use?

Answer (score 5):

You need to update Rubygems, this is not a carrierwave issue.
`sudo gem update --system` or `gem update --system` depends on your setup.

Comment: I do you meant by depends on your setup. Can state an example?. Really appriciate it

Answer (score 3):

You need to update rubygems, but **first** you need to fix the broken gemspecs.

Open `.../specifications/carrierwave-0.6.2.gemspec` in an editor, and remove all instances of `#<YAML::Syck::DefaultKey:0x718a860d0a98>`.  (Or `sed -i 's/#<.*> //' blah.gemspec`.)

Then run `gem update --system` as described elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

For me this problem arose with the version of Ruby I was using with RVM.  When attempting to install the carrierwave gem in ruby 1.8.7 it failed and my app was using ruby 1.9.3.

I resolved it by having the file `.rvmrc` in the root level of my app have the correct version of ruby I needed:

```
rvm use ruby-1.9.3-p385
```